# Select part of a string between two values SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, substring, charindex

I'm attempting to select a part of a strint between 2 values, i've managed to get it working to about 90% but then get an error -

```
SUBSTRING(TranText, CHARINDEX('x', TranText) + 1, LEN(TranText) - CHARINDEX('x', TranText) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(TranText)))
```

The field it is querying is like so

> Start Date : 01/02/2013 50 x 156.00/MX + 207.64

with the desired result being

> 156.00

Now I think the issue is because sometimes the X can have a space before or after it, or no space at all. It gets through about 114,000 rows before throwing

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

But am struggling to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main root cause could be because `LEN(@QRY) - CHARINDEX('x', @QRY)-CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@QRY))` is less than zero ie, negative value. This in turn will throw error in `SUBSTRING` since the minimum index for SUBSTRING is zero. Therefore we check that condition in a case statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(TranText) - CHARINDEX('x',TranText)-CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(TranText)) >= 0 THEN
SUBSTRING(TranText, CHARINDEX('x', TranText) + 1, LEN(TranText) - CHARINDEX('x', TranText) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(TranText)))
ELSE NULL END
FROM YOURTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Used `REPLACE` function and then parsed.

```
DECLARE @string AS VARCHAR(100),  @result AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @nStart AS int

SET @string = 'Start Date : 01/02/2013 50 x 156.00/MX + 207.64'
SET @result = REPLACE(@string, '/', '')
SET @nStart = CHARINDEX('x', @result) + 1
SET @result = SUBSTRING(@result, @nStart, CHARINDEX('M',@result) - @nStart)

SELECT @result
```